# Custom http methods on Cloud9-IDE

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver, cloud9-ide

I've written some API code for a project of mine, on my local machine (Wampserver), there's no problem sending custom request methods, and the stack handles them the same as GET and POST.

In Cloud9, however, all the basic methods go to the application bootstrap (a PHP file), but custom method names, for example "GENERATE", which I totally made-up, is stopped *before* the PHP bootstrapper with the following message: "Something went wrong! Server timed out or sent incomplete response" with error code 502.

I attempted to investigate and fix it myself, but couldn't. I don't even know which behaviour (Wampserver or Cloud9) is the default expected behaviour.

Can anyone help? How do I tell Cloud9 instances to handle custom methods the same as regular ones?